# How to select a datetime related to timezone in mysql for each user(if users has a different timezones)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a system where I need to schedule messages.
Each user has its own timezone.
I have one server and server timezone is set to `EET`.
Db tables:

```
messages:
  id int not null,
  user_id int,
  schedule DATETIME DEFAULT NULL

user:
   id
   name
   timezone: string (php compatible timezone string e.g. Europe/Paris, Europe/Budapest, etc)
```

So I want to create a cron job, to check the database each minute and check if there are any messages I need to send. 
But here I got stuck with these timezones.

I store DateTime with timezone offset, like so:

`new \DateTime('2019-01-01 01:01:01', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));`

So now I have a problem:
I can't use such query, because timezone is not checked.

```
SELECT * FROM messages as m 
JOIN user as u 
ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE m.schedule <= NOW() ORDER BY id DESC;
```

So I need to find a solution, how to get messages according to a user timezone.
Example:

```
1st user timezone: `CET + 2`
2nd user timezone: `CET + 3`
server time: `CET + 5`
I need to get messages according to each users DateTime + timezone.
```

Maybe store it in UTC and compare on php side, but I think there might be a better solution.

one more solution is to `SELECT DISTINCT timezone from user`

and then select messages according to each time zone separately.

Comment: @JoeYdoanRauzes Hi, you probably don't get the question. I need to select `messages` that needs to be sent on `schedule` time if `schedule time <= NOW() in each user timezone` (timezone is stored in `user.timezone` field.